# jquery: how to select parent and exclude children

Tags: jquery

assuming i have

```
<div class="myclass">
    <div>parent<div>
    <div>parent<div>
    <div>
       parent
       <div>child<div>
    <div>
    <div>parent<div>
</div>
```

if i wanted to select all the "li" parent excluding the li child...how can i do that?

`$(".myclass div")` ?

Comment: First there are no "li" tags in your HTML you are showing.  Second do you want all parents that have zero children?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using:

```
$(".myclass > div")
```

will select just the direct children instead of all descendants.

Answer (score 0):

use `$(".myclass div:has(div)")`